# How can I prevent TOC from appearing in TOC in LyX?

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

I'm using the `book` class and I already tried everything that prevents the Table of Contents being listed in itself that works for LaTeX, but nothing works in LyX.

Comment: The ToC doesn't appear in the ToC by default, so you must have done something to make it appear in the first place. Can you trim your document down to the minimum showing the problem, and edit your question to include either the exported LaTeX source, or the `.lyx` file itself?

Comment: For the standard book class there will be no such entry. There must be a command after your title "TableOfContents" like `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{....}` or something else in the pramble, see Document->Settings->LaTeX preamble.

Comment: @Herbert Exaclty I used \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} right after the

Comment: @user41221: But that will insert only an entry for "Abtract". Place the lyx file for a download then I can say more.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time, how can I add the lyx file? :)

Comment: I found out that the problem is on tocbibind package. Now I have to find out how to include the nottoc option. Sorry for the incorrect way of posting this question. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem caused by a user error.